# Why isnt my Information being sent to my database and why does it create random duplicates of the entries already in the database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I am working on sending information to my backend realtime database through firebase. We have created a form to try and send/store information to our backend, but when we use it only creates a temporary entry on the page and does not store the information on the backend. Also oddly enough it duplicates our manual database entries and creates temporary duplicate cards

This is our current create-restaurant.ts using angular fire

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { cards } from '../cards/cards.model';
import { RestaurantService } from './restaurant.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-restaurant',
  templateUrl: './create-restaurant.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-restaurant.component.css']
})
export class CreateRestaurantComponent implements OnInit{

  constructor(private rs: RestaurantService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  AddRestaurant(cards: cards) {
    this.rs.addRestaurants(cards);
  }
}
```

**and this is also our current service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { cards } from "../cards/cards.model";
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/compat/database';

@Injectable(
    {providedIn: 'root'}
)
export class RestaurantService {

    constructor(private db:AngularFireDatabase) {}

    getRestaurants() {
        return this.db.list<cards>("restaurants").valueChanges();
    }

    getRestaurant(index:number){

    }

    addRestaurants(cards:cards) {
        this.db.list<cards>("restaurants").push(cards)
    }
}
```